Computing $\# (C \cap D)$ in $\Bbb P^2$
The following is stated in Hartshorne.

If $X$ is a non-singular projective surface over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $C$ any non-singular curve on $X$ and $D$ any curve meeting $C$ transversally we have that

$$
\# (C \cap D)=\deg_C(\mathcal{O}_X(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C).
$$
I'm trying to grasp what this is saying, but I don't quite understand what is $\deg_C$ and how does this degree of $\mathcal{O}_X(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C$ capture the number of intersection points.
If we consider for example $\Bbb P^2$ and $C$ is given by $y = 0$ and $D$ by $x^3-x^2z-yz^3 =0$, then inuitively the number of intersection points should be $3$, but how can I verify this by calculating
$$
\deg_C(\mathcal{O}_X(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C)?
$$
Since $\Bbb P^2$ is in addition smooth is
$$
\deg_C(\mathcal{O}_X(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C) = \int_C c_1(\mathcal{O}_X(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C)?
$$
If so, can this be used to calculate $\deg_C(\mathcal{O}_X(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C)$ or is calculating the first Chern class of this thing even harder.

You can interpret $\mathcal{O}_C$ via $\iota_*\mathcal{O}_C$ as a sheaf on $X$. Then by the projection formula (I don't have the exact reference to the statement in Hartshorne at hand right now ...) you get
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}_X(D) \otimes \iota_*\mathcal{O}_C \cong \iota_* (\mathcal{O}_C \otimes \iota^*\mathcal{O}_X(D)).
\end{equation}
Now $\mathcal{O}_C \otimes \iota^*\mathcal{O}_X(D) = \iota^*\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ is just a divisor on the curve $C$, precisely (and unsurprisingly) the one cut out by $D$. In particular, it has a degree.
The phrase $\deg_C(\bullet)$ says that you are computing the the degree of a divisor on the curve $C$.
